# Magento: Sort order of getCustomer->getAddresses()

Tags: magento

I'm trying to change the sort order of the addresses collection which is used in the Magento checkout dropdown (select) for shipping address.

I'd like to change the sort order to be by 'Company name', rather than the default which is by id.

```
foreach ($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses() as $address) {
                $options[] = array(
                    'value' => $address->getId(),
                    'label' => $address->format('oneline')
                );
            }
```

I have tried adjusting to this:

```
foreach ($this->getCustomer()->getAddresses()->addAttributeToSort('company', 'ASC') as $address) {
```

But this results in an error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `getAddresses()` the collection is loaded and you can't apply your sorting anymore. You have to access the collection before it has been loaded.

Try it this way:

```
$addressCollection = $this->getCustomer()->getAddressesCollection()->addAttributeToSort('company', 'ASC');
$addresses = $addressCollection->getItems();

foreach ($addresses as $address){
 //...do whatever you need
}
```